# How to Load previous version of jquery on specific wordpress page alone

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress page where jQuery 1.7.2 is needed, so i tried this

```
if (!is_admin()&&(is_page(433))) { add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11); }
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/jquerymin.js', array(), '1.7.2');
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

This code doesn't load the jquery 1.7.2 on page with id 433. I tried to include this on functions.php, in header.php but it doesn't seems to be working.

Am i missing something?

I am using wordpress 3.7.1

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wrap that code in a function that gets called on the 'init' action.

Something like:

```
add_action('init', 'my_function', 100);
function my_function(){
//Your code
}
```

That's untested but it should help Wordpress fire your code at the correct time. You may need to adjust the '100' value.

Thinking about it... 'init' might be too early. Wordpress might not know the current page ID by then. Perhaps try some other hooks further down the line if 'init' doesn't work.